# How to connect Flash Builder 4 application to the remote mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, flash, location, validation, builder

I want to get data from a database of my site.
In the setting of the project point out Root URL: http://***.***.*.***:****
But what to set in Root folder?

Already tried the two dozen variants and Validate location does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information would be helpful here, but in a nutshell you need to create/expose some sort of service(s) on your server to accept and respond to requests.  These services act as the intermediary between the database on your server and your client application.  Here's some info from the flex docs: [Implementing services for data-centric applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4720494c2120d433845c-8000.html)